# ContextBroker dont run at localhost

Tags: fiware-orion

I try to use contextbroker in centos in localhost, and the service start, but in 30 seconds, the service stop automaticall, no errors,  i try to use rest client to connect and receive error 0.

```
[alex@alex ~]$ contextBroker --version
0.19.0   
Copyright 2013 Telefonica Investigacion y Desarrollo, S.A.U Orion Context Broker is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.    
Orion Context Broker is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more details.    
Telefonica I+D
```

and

```
[root@alex alex]# contextBroker -fg -t 0-255
DEBUG@15:18:25 paConfig.cpp[892]: setting trace levels to '0-255'
DEBUG@15:18:25 paConfig.cpp[893]: Leaving function paConfigActions
DEBUG@15:18:25 contextBroker.cpp[1341]: dbName: 'orion'
INFO@15:18:25 contextBroker.cpp[1348]: Orion Context Broker is running
DEBUG@15:18:25 contextBroker.cpp[1144]: dbName: 'orion'
DEBUG@15:18:25 MongoGlobal.cpp[101]: dbName: 'orion'    
DEBUG@15:18:25 sem.cpp[107]: mongoConnect taking the 'mongo' semaphore for 'connecting to mongo'    
DEBUG@15:18:25 sem.cpp[109]: mongoConnect has the 'mongo' semaphore  
ERROR@15:18:25 MongoGlobal.cpp[123]: Database Startup Error (cannot connect to mongo - doing 100 retries with a 1000 microsecond interval)
```

Comment: In order to debug this issue please edit your question to include the following information: 1) contextBroker version (you can get it running `contextBroker --version`), 2) the output of a foreground execution, i.e. running CB as follows `contextBroker -fg -t 0-255`

Comment: Is your MongoDB database running properly at localhost?

Answer (score 1):

The error trace:

```
Database Startup Error (cannot connect to mongo - doing 100 retries with a 1000 microsecond interval)
```

means that Orion Context Broker is not able to connect to MongoDB at startup. Please, check that you MongoDB is installed properly (in localhost by default, if you want to change this setting have a look to [this section in the Orion Administration Manual](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Running_Orion_Context_Broker)).